# Is Visitoridentification relevant in Sitecore Jss based Implementation?

Tags: jss

Visitoridentification is important in Asp.Net MVC-based implementation, but I'm curious if Sitecore Jss-based implementations also require this to be enabled.

I observe that the Sitecore CD server is receiving a lot of requests for visitor identification. Can you advise if it would be best to disable this in the JSS implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is... It depends:

If you are on XM then there is no need for it, you should be tracking analytics and personalizing via a composable solution, Google Analytics, Sitecore Personalize etc...

Do you use xDB and want to track analytics with XPs feature set? If so, that's the process to do it.

The caveat to that is, do you really need XP in a headless world, it reduces the feature set you can use in headless. For example if you are building with Next.js, your pages need to be SSR not SSG, which is losing performance.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Richard. `VisitorIdentification` is necessary for Sitecore Analytics to determine if the visitor is a robot. If Sitecore XP (with xConnect/xDB) is used, this is required or else analytics will not be collected for the `JSS app`. For XM (CMS-only) apps, this should be removed. `VisitorIdentification` detection only runs once for a given analytics ID, so this is not a recurring operation once cookies are established.